# How do you pull data from two objects using a soql query?

Tags: soql

```
    Select op.Id, op.Name, op.Install_Date__c, op.Scheduled_Go_Live_Date__c, 
(SELECT Id, Field, OldValue, NewValue, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityFieldHistory) 
FROM Opportunity op WHERE op.Scheduled_Go_live_Change_Count__c != 'null' AND op.Scheduled_Go_live_Change_Count__c != '' AND op.Boolean_check_install_date__c = 
TRUE
```

Here's my issue.

I have had fields modified in....600-800 opportunities, that WHERE is the check to see if they have been modified. What I want to do is pull the opphistory (it's an object that has a field opporunityId that matches with the opportunity object Id field it also has the old data)

So how would I go about getting the old data on the op.Install_Date__c and the op.Scheduled_Go_Live_Date__c fields from the opportunity? Because my SOQL statement comes up with this error:

> NewValue, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityFieldHistory) FROM Opportunity
>                                 ^
>   ERROR at Row:1:Column:136
>   Didn't understand relationship 'OpportunityFieldHistory' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 10):

The child relationship name is `Histories`. You can find the correct API Name of the Child Relationship for any such subquery using a script like the below:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Opportunity.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == OpportunityFieldHistory.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

Comment: +1 for providing the script to get the relationship name.

Comment: `Select op.Name, op.Id (Select OldValue, NewValue FROM Histories) From Opportunity op where op.Boolean_check_install_date__c = TRUE`  should work? Because that leaves me with an 'Unknown Error parsing query

Comment: You need a comma after the op.Id. Also, there's really not much point to Aliasing your object. Since there is a character count limit in Apex (although it is admittedly quite high). I'd recommend not doing this as it unnecessarily bloats character count and adds nothing to the code. `Select Name, Id, (Select OldValue, NewValue FROM Histories) From Opportunity where Boolean_check_install_date__c = TRUE` [Lastly, you can get the child relationship names from the WSDL as well](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_generate_wsdl.htm)